# How do I do the equivalent of a Graphics.DrawString() in WPF?

Tags: wpf, string, drawing

I'm creating a WPF application (in C#) and I need to be able to draw strings using the C# code, not the XAML. The strings  will be changing rapidly, so whatever method I use should be able to reflect that. I like the graphics.drawstring method in windows forms. Is there anything similar I can use in WPF?

Edit: Creating FormattedText seems to be the answer, but what is the drawingContext? How do I find it? What I really want to do is put this text into the children of a canvas. How is that done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an entire section of MSDN explaining how to [draw formatted text in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752098.aspx).  This allows you to draw, via code, on any drawing context.

Comment: Ok, I understand how to create a FormattedText, but how do I put it into the children of a canvas?